# При увеличении изображения на canvas оно размывается. Как с этим бороться?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Слева размытое изображение на канвасе, справа исходное изображение, надо что бы было с пикселями, а оно размывает, не знаю как бороться.

[image]

```
        c=skinImage.width/64;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 256;// * scale;
        canvas.height = 256;// * scale;
        //we assign the same classname the image has, for CSS purposes
        canvas.setAttribute('class', skinImage.getAttribute('class'));
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var s = scale;
        //draw the head
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 8*c,  8*c,  8*c, 8*c,  4*s,  0*s,  8*s, 8*s);
        //draw the mask
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 40*c,  8*c,  8*c, 8*c,  4*s,  0*s,  8*s, 8*s);
        //draw the body
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 20*c, 20*c, 8*c, 12*c, 4*s,  8*s,  8*s, 12*s);
        //draw the left leg
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 4*c,  20*c, 4*c, 12*c, 4*s,  20*s, 4*s, 12*s);
        //draw the right leg
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 4*c,  20*c, 4*c, 12*c, 8*s,  20*s, 4*s, 12*s);
        //draw the left arm
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 44*c, 20*c, 4*c, 12*c, 0*s,  8*s,  4*s, 12*s);
        //draw the right arm
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 44*c, 20*c, 4*c, 12*c, 12*s, 8*s,  4*s, 12*s);
        //draw down leftleg
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 20*c,  52*c,  4*c, 12*c,  4*s,  20*s, 4*s, 12*s);
        //draw down lefthand
        context.drawImage(skinImage, 36*c,  52*c,  4*c, 12*c,  0*s,  8*s,  4*s, 12*s);

        //we replace the image with the canvas
        skinImage.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, skinImage);
```

Использую такой код, s-это во сколько раз должно увеличиться, оно увеличивается, но в результате оно размывается вместо того что бы нормально отобразиться, я не знаю что делать подскажите.

Comment: Попробуйте context.imageSmoothingEnabled= false

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3Fz6/e2V2A9skb Не получилось...

Comment: Возможно надо добавить браузер специфику: https://plnkr.co/edit/Iazvs2adl4dT58cHewxa?p=info

Comment: Вы гений спасибо, все заработало, ваш комментарий можно назнчить ответом?

Comment: Вынес в ответ с примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи установки свойства context.imageSmoothingEnabled в false. Кроссбраузерная установка:

```
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

[image: comparasion]

Рабочий пример на [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Iazvs2adl4dT58cHewxa?p=preview)

[Страница на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled)